# Switching contents of a webpage with python CGI

Tags: python, json, api, url, stream

I'm trying to learn by doing and i was messing around with twitch's API and JSON and got a list of the top 25 streams on their site to print out (splinksy.com) shows what i mean. Now i want to be able to make it so that when you click on a link it removes the text from the page and replaces it with a full screen embed of the stream, i know how to get python to show the embed i just don't know how to get it to work with page-urls such as `?channel=` or just replacing content without refreshing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a click listener You can load the content of HTML body required to display a full screen embed of the stream using AJAX and replace content of a division which spans the whole body of current HTML page.

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  $.get('?channel=1',
    function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    }
  );
});
```

As you are loading content from other website you should use following code:

```
<iframe width="800" height="400" id="content"></iframe>
<a data-url="http://www.twitch.tv/esltv_dota">esltv_dota</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(){
      $('#content').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-url'));
    });
  });
<script>
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to call a python function whenever .click(function() gets called?

Comment: You can call a `url` which can served by a python function. You can replace `?channel=1` by the `url` from which you will get the HTML body of new page.

Comment: Can you give me an example? i dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: Are loading the content from other website? If yes then you should use <iframe>.

Comment: Thats the thing, im trying to use iframe but nothing happens can you look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442193/adding-a-stream-embed-on-click, im trying to embed the iframe one onclick, how would i do that?