# Adding a stream embed on click

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, cgi

I'm trying to make it so when you click a div it replaces the div with an embed (https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/embedding.md). Currently what i have is this: http://pastebin.com/5N3hqWz3 (live at www.splinksy.com) Im able to get divs to replace to "test" when i click them, but i cant get them to be replaced by the embed object.

Also, is it possible to replace the whole webpage with the embed once they click one of the links (erase the list and replace it with one embed)